# Issues with jquery roundabout not firing moveClockwiseThroughBack

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues with roundabout not firing the `moveClockwiseThroughBack` and `moveCounterClockwiseThroughBack` callbacks. The site does not provide any examples of this in use so I am wondering if anyone has had any experience with it.

Here is the code I am using to initialize the roundabout, only issue is that they do not fire the functions.

jQuery version: 1.9.1 via CDN
Roundabout version 2.4.2 via localhost

```
   $('#cellWrapper').roundabout({
    childSelector: 'div',
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
    enableDrag: true,
    dropEasing: 'easeOutBounce',
    triggerFocusEvents: true,
    moveClockwiseThroughBack: function () {
        console.log('ye');
    },
    moveCounterClockwiseThroughBack: function () {
        console.log('ye');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following code to work properly, however i was unsure if it was meant to be set as such.

```
     var Blah = $('#cellWrapper').roundabout({
    childSelector: 'div',
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'easeOutQuad',
    enableDrag: true,
    dropEasing: 'easeOutBounce',
    triggerFocusEvents: true
});

Blah.bind('moveClockwiseThroughBack', FireBack);

function FireBack () {
    console.log('ye');
}
```